# PyroCms / in page slug

Tags: php, pyrocms

Im creating a new page to display in the sidebar navigation on my pyroCms page.
I want the page url to be "auctions/create" but im unabled to since it will not accept "/" sign in the slug field.

Is there another way of doing this? I just want dynamically to be able to create links for the sidebar and make it go to modules.

Hope you understand.

Jonas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you choose the "Site Link (URI)" option when creating your link, you should be able to put a link with a slash in the "Site Link (URI)" field.